# foreach on gridview rows always run 1 time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach, rows

I have a `Gridview` and `Object data source`, and use `Object data source` for binding `Gridview`, as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" DataSourceID="ObjDataSource">
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjDataSource" runat="server"
        SelectCountMethod="Count" SelectMethod="Get"
        TypeName="App.Data.Products" EnablePaging="true"
        StartRowIndexParameterName="skip"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="take">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="id" Name="ID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I have a button and wrote below code on `OnClick` event:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdProducts.Rows)
    {
        Response.Write("A<br />");
    }
```

When I run, I see more than 1 rows in `Gridview`, but when I click on button, the `A` wrote just 1 time !

Also when I Write `grdProducts.Rows.Count`, I got 1 as result.

What is the wrong part?

Thanks !

Comment: Are aware of postback concept in web applications?

Comment: hmmm, I think I know something about that.

Comment: Something else you wanna show us, because this looks like alright.

Comment: Moreover rows count is 1, it means Response.Write statement will execute once only

Comment: @صفی no, that is all I have as code.

Comment: @Rahul yes, and the problem is, why execute only 1 time, when I have more than 1 rows in gridview

Comment: @MehdiDehghani if `grdProducts.Rows.Count` = 1 you don't have more than 1 row.

Comment: Response.Write causes full postback. May be that's why, its printing 1

Comment: bro, when I run the project, in browser, I see more that 1 row.

Comment: try printing out the data from the row(s). You might get a better picture of what's going wrong. Also print the data to a label or literal instead of response.write.

Comment: I tired some way for `log` the result and in all of them, I got 1 time execution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to something like this:

```
string textToPrint = string.empty;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdProducts.Rows)
    {
        textToPrint += "A<br />";
    }

Response.Write(textToPrint);
```

Comment: still I have 1 `A` as output !

Comment: So what are the contents of the single row you're getting back? Is it the first or last row or something else totally? I think you've got some sort of post back issue happening here.

Comment: Grid filling by list of a class, including `ID, Title, Image and CreatedDate`, in the current test, I have 6 records in `table` and `grid`, but `foreach` executed 1 time only.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Post your page_load method code in your question